# Uncaught ReferenceError: popup not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a help message popup when we click the help button. for help message popup there is a separate javascript code. when I click the help button I am getting the following message from HTML console.

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstro is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (superdm.js?v=-356232721:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4-ver-1548530623000.js:4737)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.2.4-ver-1548530623000.js:4549)
```

Can anyone suggest how to make it right?

JavaScript:

```
function initHelp() {
    $("#customHelp").click(function(){
        bootstro.start(".customHelp", {
            prevButton : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-info bootstro-prev-btn">Prev «</button>',
            nextButton : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-info bootstro-next-btn">Next »</button>',
            finishButton : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success bootstro-finish-btn">Close Help</button>',
            onComplete : function(params)
            {
            },
            onExit : function(params)
            {
            },
            onStep : function(params)
            {
            }
        });    
    });
}

Button:
    <a wicket:id="helpButton" id="customHelp" class="nav-link" href="#">help</a>

Bootstrap:
<div class="customHelp" data-bootstro-placement="right" data-bootstro-width="500px" data-bootstro-title="Custom help">
```

Comment: `bootstro` doesn't exist when you are calling `.start` on it. Check where/how you're initialising it.

Comment: Well, `bootstro` is not defined. Are you loading it? Is it loaded at the correct time?

Comment: how to load bootstro. can you please tell me

Comment: @Krishna we don't know *what* it is, neither how your project is set up.